# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my expense class, branch id is a foreign key. to display I got data from Sql about expense detail along branch id, branch description. Trying to set virtual property (branch) with branch description.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: a) Please don't post [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode); b) on what line do you get that exception?

Comment: I got error on expense.Branch.Oid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should include your database table and your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Branch branch = new Branch();
branch.Oid = (int)reader["br_oid"];
branch.Description = (string)reader["br_description"];
expense.Branch = branch;
```

solved my problem.